# How to exclude a certain domain from email using regexp without negative lookahead?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

For the following data, how can I exclude all email with gmail.com as domain in one line on the where clause with REGEXP_LIKE? 
Due to database constraint and business logic, I need to exclude it with the regex on REGEXP_LIKE. Any idea on how to append to the regex(no negative lookahead due to plsql) to exclude?
Please advise. Thanks!

```
WITH t AS
( 
 SELECT 'brucewayne.1981@gmail.com' email
    FROM dual  
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'clark_kent@gmail.com'
    FROM dual  
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT '1Tonystark.1980@gmail.com'
    FROM dual  
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'peter@parker.1989@yahoo.com'
    FROM dual  
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'pete.1989@yahoo.com'
    FROM dual  
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'yahoo.com'
    FROM dual  
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT '123@yahoo.com' FROM dual
)    
SELECT *
  FROM t    
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (EMAIL,'^[^.]?[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&''*+-/=?^_`{|}~\.]{1,62}[^.]?@[^.-]?[A-Za-z0-9.-]{1,253}[^.-]\.[A-Za-z]{2,256}$')
```

Comment: Your regular expression will match invalid e-mail addresses such as `example@@......@.com` ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3bba5dd7aa2393bde84299f7c3fc80f1)).

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT LIKE` to exclude

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (EMAIL,'^[^.]?[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&''*+-/=?^_`{|}~\.]{1,62}[^.]?@[^.-]?[A-Za-z0-9.-]{1,253}[^.-]\.[A-Za-z]{2,256}$')
AND EMAIL NOT LIKE '%@gmail.com'
```

Comment: due to database constraint and business logic, I need to exclude it with the regex on REGEXP_LIKE. Any idea on how to append to the regex(no negative lookahead due to plsql) to exclude?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this in a single regexp without negative lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `NOT REGEXP_LIKE` containing `'@gmail.com$'` pattern, where `$` sign is used in order to specify the e-mail address ending with `@gmail.com` :

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE( email,'@gmail.com$')
```

**OR**
alternatively by filtering out string through the extracted part after `@` sign :

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR( email,'[^@]+$') != 'gmail.com';
```

**Update :** (*without **unequality** or **NOT IN** as you'd like*) you can also use

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE NVL(INSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR( email,'[@gmail.com]+$'),'@gmail.com'),0)=0;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7e9c712b9fd0be9b6a274fb33d2ce5c9)</kbd>

Comment: due to database constraint and business logic, I need to exclude it with the regex on REGEXP_LIKE. Any idea on how to append to the regex(no negative lookahead due to plsql) to exclude?

Comment: I think he still needs the regexp to match other email addresses, just exclude `@gmail.com`.

Comment: But you removed the regexp that checks that it's a valid email.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, but Im looking for a single regex that does the exclusion of domain on email and validation of all other emails. The equality and not in does work but looking for a single regex only. Please advise. Thanks!